# Checking the type of the Array elements

Tags: java, list, arraylist, character

I've managed to add the user input into the `ArrayList`.

Now I want to split this *list*. So that letters are with letters, numbers are with numbers.

I.e, I want to obtain two separate *lists* (or arrays): *digits* and *letters*. Is there a way to do this?

I'm new to java, so for now I don't see where to go. I think that I need to check each of the elements of the array against the type `int` and `char` (`String` ?), but I don't understand how to do it.

```
public class BaseClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner takeData = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        String str = takeData.nextLine();
        ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            chars.add(c);
        }
    
        System.out.println(chars);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want to sort it so that letters are with letters, numbers are
> with numbers

So you want to sort the given list so that digits will be separated from letters.

You can do it by defining a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) (*which is a special object used to compare two objects and define the order of elements of a collection, stream, etc.*).

Down below is a *comparator* that firstly determines whether the given character is a digit and then compares characters according to their natural ordering ([*have a look at this tutorial for more information on Java-8 comparators*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing)).

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>(List.of('1', 'a', '2', 'b', 'c', '3'));

Comparator<Character> lettersFirst = 
    Comparator.comparing((Character ch) -> Character.isDigit(ch))
              .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());

chars.sort(lettersFirst);
System.out.println(chars);
```

**Output**

```
[a, b, c, 1, 2, 3]
```

---

> I want to obtain two separate lists (or arrays): digits and letters.

If you just need to separate digit from letters without sorting them and omit other symbols, you can use static methods of the `Character` class [`isLetter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) and [`isDigit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)).

```
String str = "lemon 123 abc";
List<Character> digits = new ArrayList<>();
List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char next = str.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(next)) {
        digits.add(next);
    } else if (Character.isLetter(next)) {
        letters.add(next);
    }
}
    
System.out.println("Letters: " + letters);
System.out.println("Digits: " + digits);
```

**Output**

```
Letters: [l, e, m, o, n, a, b, c]
Digits: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of solving it. With external libraries, see article on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-string-number).

```
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

public boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
    if (strNum == null) {
        return false; 
    }
    return pattern.matcher(strNum).matches();
}
```

Another alternative is to convert char to `int` and compare them against [ASCII table](https://theasciicode.com.ar)

```
for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
  chars.add(c);
  int letter = c;
  if (letter >= 48 && letter <= 57) {
    System.out.println("Number: " + letter);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Something else: " + letter);
  }
}
```

Also, there is an even better core Java way with these methods:

```
Character.isDigit(letter);
Character.isLetter(letter);
```

See more details in [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_characters.htm)

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner takeData = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = takeData.nextLine();
    
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    
    // checking a character is alphabetic or not with ascii value
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
      int ch = c;
      if ((ch >= 65 && ch <= 91) || (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122)) {
        chars.add(c);
      }
    }
    // checking a character is numeric or not wrt ascii value
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
      int ch = c;
      if ((ch >= 48 && ch <= 57)) {
        chars.add(c);
      }
    }
    System.out.println(chars);
}
```

}

Comment: Please add information instead of raw code: explain what the OP is doing wrong and how you corrected it in your code; or in this case: what is your code doing, in plain english, not Java.

Comment: I get an output to the console in the form of an ASCI with such a condition (only numbers). But anyway, thanks. I'll think about what can be done about it.